# Add extra query string to src attribute's value of an iframe element that has been generated or outputted by wp_oembed_get() function

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, query-string, oembed

I want to add an extra query string to the src attribute's value of the iframe element. I want to achieve this by using PHP or WordPress and not by JavaScript.

The thing is that I want to use Youtube iFrame API, which is only possible if the iframe has a query string in which **enablejspai=1** src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"

Currently, the user will copy-paste the video URL and my code will grab that URL and will convert it to the iframe element.

```
$embed_code = wp_oembed_get( $video_post_url);
echo $embed_code;
```

The above code will output an iframe element with src attribute with value of just plain url but I want to add a query string to it and make it plain-url?enablejsapi=1 So I can use Youtube Iframe API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the url as follows:

```
// Load value.
$iframe = wp_oembed_get( $video_post_url );

// Use preg_match to find iframe src.
preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', $iframe, $matches);

// Iframe URL
$src = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, Man! The actual code I used to modify the src attribute:

$iframe = wp_oembed_get( $video_url );

preg_match( '/src="(.+?)"/', $embed_code, $matches );

$src = $matches[1];

echo str_replace( $src, $src . '&enablejsapi=1', $embed_code );